# Does Nim support type inference?

Tags: nim-lang

I saw this example in Nim, it requires explicit type specification for `int` and `bool`, although there's enough information to infer both (like TypeScript would do).

If those types removed it won't compile, does Nim support type inference?

```
import sequtils

let list = @[1, 2, 4]
echo list.filter do (x: int) -> bool: x > 2
```

Comment: This works: https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=283F. As @genotrance mentioned, you can use `auto`. The type inference you referred to is working in this part of your snippet: `let list = @[1, 2, 4]`. The explicit way to do the same declaration would be `let list: seq[int] = @[1, 2, 4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the [`=>`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/sugar.html#%3D%3E.m%2Cuntyped%2Cuntyped) macro from the sugar module.

```
echo list.filter(x => x > 2)
```

From documentation:

Syntax sugar for anoynmous procedures.

```
macro `=>`(p, b: untyped): untyped
```

```
proc passTwoAndTwo(f: (int, int) -> int): int =
  f(2, 2)

passTwoAndTwo((x, y) => x + y) # 4
```

Syntax sugar for procedure types.

```
macro `->`(p, b: untyped): untyped
```

```
proc pass2(f: (float, float) -> float): float =
  f(2, 2)

# is the same as:

proc pass2(f: proc (x, y: float): float): float =
  f(2, 2)
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Comment: @Jason I did add a link to its documentation, I didn't think there is a need to add anything more to it. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

> The auto type can only be used for return types and parameters. For return types it causes the compiler to infer the type from the routine body:

http://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/manual.html#types-auto-type

Comment: It won't compile if `bool: x > 2` type removed from the body.

Comment: bool in that context is the return value of the procedure. You can change it to auto and try again.

Comment: I see, I didn't realised that `auto: ...` needs to be typed anyway.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin If you want to know the syntax to use, you should read the documentation. And see alexdreptu's answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Does Nim support type inference?

According to [the Homepage](https://nim-lang.org/), Nim has a …

> Modern type system with local **type inference**, tuples, generics and sum types.

[**bold** emphasis mine]

Also, [the language manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html) mentions type inference in about 10 different places.

And the [*Comparison* table on the *Nim for TypeScript Programmers* Wiki page](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/wiki/Nim-for-TypeScript-Programmers#Comparison) lists type inference as a feature.

So, in conclusion, the answer is "Yes", at least according to the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks, why the example is not working then? `bool: x > 2` - that part should be exactly the local type inference

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin So this question wasn't the question you wanted to ask.